# Drawing arc by centerpoint, radius and azimuth in KML?

Tags: kml, wgs84

How do I generate lon/lat coordinates for an arc/sector?

Coordinates can be used/filled into a KML file. Pointers to geometric formula or a program applying the formula are sought.

Radius is 2 km and location is Europe North East. Accuracy is not a issue at this point.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Approximately what sort of maximum radii and what region of the Earth are you contemplating? And what kind of accuracy? Please edit more details into your question, via the button between share and flag, above.

Comment: In case you need to do a lot of calculations, you should research (or ask about as a separate Q) suitable geo/cogo libraries for the languages you'd like to use.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @MartinF Region was Northen Finland and a maximum radius about 10 km. The answer below was sufficient by time of 5 years ago, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get away with treating the geographic coords (lon-lat) *as though* they were projected coords and using simple planar cogo (coordinate geometry). Psuedocode:

```
sector-radius-deg = 360-deg * sector-radius-km / earth-circumference-km
for azimuth = init-azimuth to end-azimuth step delta-azimuth
    sector-point-lon-deg = center-lon-deg + sector-radius-deg * sin (azimuth)
    sector-point-lat-deg = center-lat-deg + sector-radius-deg * cos (azimuth)
```

(but ensure azimuth is suitably converted for sin/cos functions)